# How can I resolve eclipse content assist to show correct struct

Tags: c, linux-kernel, eclipse-cdt, content-assist

From this image, we can see how eclipse recognizes the macro, but is not using it correctly..[image: eclipse content assist wrong struct]

I am trying to display the fields using eclipse content assist from the

```
#define current get_current()
```

macro defined in /arch/x86/include/asm/current.h

get_current returns a pointer to a struct struct_task as seen below:

```
static __always_inline struct task_struct *get_current(void)
{
    return this_cpu_read_stable(current_task);
}
```

I'd like to type current->state for example so the values from `struct task_struct {` populate instead of (for some weird reason), the struct members of `struct call_path;`

Comment: rebuilding index resolved this

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by ensuring indexing was enabled in the section "C/C++ General"-> Enable Indexer [check]